# AIR 2 app vs Silverlight 4 out-of-browser app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, air

Anyone released any Silverlight 4.0 out-of-browser app yet?  does it compare to AIR 2.0?

Question about Silverlight 4, it has some webview-like control where I can write HTML+CSS right?  What rendering engine does it use?  What ver of CSS does it support?  IE? IE7?

Planning to learn either [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) or [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/), but have not decided on which.

Just read the MSDN's [Hilo: Developing C++ Applications for Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708696.aspx) and I just can't imagine myself writing any native Windows app.  The language, framework and libraries are too complex and pathetic.

Comment?

Comment: +1 I'm developing in Silverlight now, but I would be interested in what the web browser control is.

Comment: It is IE for sure, since Seesmic Desktop just throws me the good old Javascript Debug prompt.  Even has Add to Favorite on right click, and it adds to my IE9 beta.  I guess it uses the IE on Windows, but what does it use on OSX? interesting...

Comment: Hmm.. the installation process is smooth, the experience slightly is better than Adobe AIR, but the Process listed in Task Manager is just a generic silver light loader (while AIR's uses appname.exe).  Uninstalling Silverlight app is uninstall only with no prompt, a little unpolished...

Comment: The web browser control is not very powerful from the developer side. It can load from url, but not much else. It's tough if you want to inject your own content.

Comment: Oh really?  AIR's web browser control is pretty powerful, I guess that's where silverlight 4 is still behind.

Comment: FYI AIR's web browser control = Safari 4.0.3 minus a few features: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/articles/air_and_webkit.html

Comment: If you were considering developing Windows Native applications, why skipping WPF as an option? Silverlight is just a subset of WPF, and it runs inside a sanbox. With WPF you have much more control without having to deal with the Win32 API and you can use libraries like this: http://code.google.com/p/berkelium-sharp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seesmic Desktop 2.0 is a good example of a Silverlight 4 application that runs out of browser.

See http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/windowsexperience/archive/2010/09/14/seesmic-releases-seesmic-desktop-2.aspx